# How to get each field value in views-views-unformatted--view-machine-name.html.twig?

Tags: views, theming, 8

I have an twig file: *views-view-unformatted--view-machine-name.html.twig*

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a view of unformatted rows.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - title: The title of this group of rows. May be empty.
 * - rows: A list of the view's row items.
 *   - attributes: The row's HTML attributes.
 *   - content: The row's content.
 * - view: The view object.
 * - default_row_class: A flag indicating whether default classes should be
 *   used on rows.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{ row.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to have `Title` and `body` *field* to be in 1 line separated by comma like:

*title, body*

How can I get value of 'title' or 'body' or any other field in this view while debugging?

I used kint(title) and kint(body) but it's not working. I also made `debug = TRUE;` in services file.

But can't figure out the way of having fields value in unformatted html twig.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As you can see in [views-view-unformatted.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21templates%21views-view-unformatted.html.twig/8.2.x), it says what also the commented code you've shown says, there is no fields variable. Therefore, this template is not used for fields.

> Available variables:
>
> - title: The title of this group of rows. May be empty.
> - rows: A list of the view's row items.
>
>   - attributes: The row's HTML attributes.
>   - content: The row's content.
> - view: The view object.
> - default_row_class: A flag indicating whether default classes should be  used on rows.

If you want to use fields in a view template, use **views-view-fields--[view-name]--[[machine-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsMjX.jpg).html.twig**. There, you can print your fields like this:

```
<span>{{ fields.title.content }},</span><span>{{ fields.body.content }}</span>
```

Comment: view_name with underscore kept, while machine-name with underscore transformed into comma

Comment: views-view-fields.html.twig can be copied from the /core/modules/views/templates folder and then renamed as above. For a given View with a machine_name of foobar, then the new name can be views-view-fields--foobar.html.twig. More info on naming conventions is available here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions

Comment: While not recommended, there are ways to get the raw field value AND the rendered field value (render array). See Sathish Sundar's anwer for the raw data value of a field and Ibrahim Samir's answer to get the HTML render array of a field.

Answer (score 31):

**I have found a Way using Kint, You can get field values in views-view--unformatted.html.twig**

**if you want a specific field**

To get text fields value

`{{row.content['#row']._entity.field machine name[0].value}}`

To get image fields src

`{{file_url(row.content['#row']._entity.field machine name.entity.uri.value)}}`

To get image alt,title,width,height

`{{row.content['#row']._entity.field machine name[0].alt/title/width/height}}`

> Note :  replace field machine name with your fields machine name

**If you Want to loop through multiple field**

```
{% for i in range(0, 10) %}
  {{ row.content['#row']._entity.body[i].value }}
{% endfor %}
```

**If you Want raw value**

```
{% for i in range(0, 10) %}
  {{ row.content['#row']._entity.body[i].value|raw }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can some one guide me how to access link fields(url and text) value separately?

Comment: This is working. Is there any other way to get the field's value?

Comment: This works great. Well done!

Comment: Where in the world is the `_entity` key documented?! It doesn't show up via `{{ dump(row.content['#row']|keys) }}`. Thanks much for your answer!

Comment: How will I print the URL? I have a field to enter the website URL and wanted to print it as @sathish-sundar mentioned. `<a href="{{row.content['#row']._entity.field_link_to_the_kb_section.value}}" target=""><img src="sites/default/files/2023-08/kbs.png" alt="values" class="box-image" /></a>`. It didn't work for me!

Answer (score 11):

I have figured a way using kint.

Inside your views-view-unformatted.html.twig use the following code to display your individual fields:

```
{% for row in rows %}

{{ row.content['#view'].style_plugin.render_tokens[ loop.index0 ]['{{ YOUR_FIELD_NAME }}'] }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How to use Image Field. When I Use field_image , there is no output. The Image URL is not displaying or rendering!

Comment: Can some one guide me how to access link fields(url and text) value separately?

Answer (score 7):

You need to create three files to override the views using twig files. 
1. views-view--foobar.html.twig
2. views-view-unformatted--foobar.html.twig
3. views-view-fields--foobar.html.twig

Purpose of all three files is described below:
1: Default theme implementation for main view template.
2: Default theme implementation to display a view of unformatted rows.
3: Default view template to display all the fields in a row.

You should use "views-view-fields--foobar.html.twig" to output each of your field on views.

Below is a sample:

```
<li>
<p>{{ fields.title.content }}</p> // Title field
<p>{{ fields.body.content }}</p> // Body field
<span>{{ fields.created.content }}</span> // Node authored date field
<a href="{{ fields.path.content }}" class="readmore"> read more </a> // Link to actual page
</li>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried the above in views-view-foobar.html.twig but not able to print a single field. I debug **fields** using kint() it shows 'nothing' array on the top.

Answer (score 5):

Below is the sample code to access field values in views-view-unformatted.html.twig file -

```
{% for row in rows %}
  {% set photo = file_url(row['content']['#row']._entity.field_page_photo.entity.fileuri) %}          
  <li><img src={{ photo }} class="img-responsive img-circle"></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Perfect! That's the thing I want to know, Thanks Renuka.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add your field value like this

```
{% for key, item in rows %}
  {{ view.style_plugin.getField(key, 'field_name') }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, there's no easy way to twig in views-views-unformatted--view-.html.twig a value from fields not part of the entity structure.

Very  to print a `text (plain)` field. So painfull to print a `flag_field`, `entity_reference` and so on.

Having to achieve this without going through  the whole view core code, I had to build this hack:

1. add a fake plain text field entity
2. hook the view field value in a custom module:
3. twig  (finally) the desired value  in template

More details here  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/288316/13760