# Get node form inside preprocess_views_view_fields()

Tags: views

how can I get the node id  through the  : preprocess_views_view_fields()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get nid (node id) from $vars as like following:

```
$vars['row']->nid
```

You can also check the `$vars` to view the structure of the object as like following:

```
dpm($vars);
```

To use `dpm();` you have to install [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module.

Comment: But there is also the case when you don't need to write preprocess function and you can use the node id directly in twig
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235897/how-can-i-get-data-from-resultrow-object-in-views-template