# How to print in twig a Flag Link field

Tags: views, 8, theming, flags

I have a views-view-unformatted.html.twig template working fine where I can print fields from a view of nodes.

Example: having i = 3, print row number 3 title

```
{{ rows[i]['content']['#row']._entity.title.0.value }}
```

This view has also a working relationship with flag. I see it working in the view preview.

How can I print the flag link inside views-view-unformatted.html.twig?

Comment: Have you tried `{{ rows[i]['content']['#row']._entity.flag_field_name.value }}`? Replace `flag_field_name` with the actual field name of the flag field.

Comment: @RickBergmann, View > Devel gives a  "link_flag" field. `{{  rows[i]['content']['#row']._entity.link_flag.value }}` is not producing anything.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing the render array. Try to use `{{ dump( rows[i]['content']['#row']._entity) }}` that should list all the fields in the render array, then you can drill into the fields, and the link_flag should be listed there. Fields are usually prefixed with `field_`. Maybe paste the output of the dump in the question if it's not too long.

Comment: Edit: I see that flag does not prefix with `field_`. I am using the flag module in 1 of my projects. I will try to replicate this case in my project and post when I find something.

Comment: kint(rows[i]['content']['#row']._relationship_entities.flag_relationship ) is giving data below. Not sure how to use it to render a flag_link ` 
 rows[i]['content']['#row']._relationship_entities.flag_relationship Drupal\flag\Entity\Flagging(27)
contentsStatic class properties (4)Iterator contents (10)Available methods (124)
→protected values -> array(10)
protected fields -> array(0)
protected fieldDefinitions -> NULL
protected languages -> NULL...
 `

Comment: Looks like there could be something renderable in the values array `protected values -> array(10)`. I tried to reproduce this but I also find it more difficult to get flag values. Usually I make view blocks and render them in twig instead of using the view-unformatted template, and I use twig block template overrides to render the fields / content in the view. I can also suggest asking for a support request in the flag project page on Drupal.org, maybe someone can suggest another option there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not being able to find better solution nor documetation, I built this working hack:

1. add a fake text field entity. IE: for articles: http://yoursite/admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields  > Add field > Add text plain field
2. hook the view in a custom module:

   ```
   function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable &$view){
     if( $view->id() == 'VIEWID' ){
       foreach($view->result as $r) {
       // from https://www.drupal.org/comment/reply/295383/12504094
       $node = $r->_entity;
       $flag_link = [
         '#lazy_builder' => ['flag.link_builder:build', [
         $node->getEntityTypeId(),
         $node->id(),
         'FLAG',
       ]],
       '#create_placeholder' => TRUE,
     ];
     $flag_link = render($flag_link);
     $r->_entity->set('field_fake_flag_field', $flag_link); //.
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. print (finally) your flag link in the twig template:

   {{ rows[i]['content']['#row']._entity.field_fake_flag_field.0.value }}

Twig is cool. It takes a while, sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I used `{{ fields.link_flag.content }}` in a views-view-fields--some_view_name.html.twig and that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have found this

```
{{ view.style_plugin.getField(KEY, 'FIELD_NAME') }}
```

at this link https://dharmeshsavaliya.wordpress.com/2020/03/26/accessing-views-row-fields-inside-views-view-unformatted-html-twig-in-drupal-8/